# mvc3 assign anonymous types or workaround

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, syntax-error, anonymous-types

I have a model that is used to modify a user's password and captures the date that the password has been changed. I am getting an error saying **property or indexer anonymous type cannot be assigned to it is read only** I get that error for both fields the password and CreateDate . I only know of 1 way to select multiple fields from entity and this is it..

```
  var old= db.registration.Where(b => b.email == getid.email).Select
(s => new { s.password, s.CreateDate }).FirstOrDefault();

                     old.CreateDate = DateTime.Now();

                     old.password = new.password;
                     db.Entry(old).State = EntityState.Modified;
                     db.SaveChanges();
```

Is there a  way that I can assign these new values without getting the error message or a workaround ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just select the default object and run with it

```
var old= db.registration.Where(b => b.email == getid.email).FirstOrDefault();
old.CreateDate = DateTime.Now();
old.password = new.password;
db.Entry(old).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();
```

The error message you're getting is likely because you're assigning to the index of an anonymous type, ie.

```
 s => new { s.password, s.CreateDate }
```

is anonymous and its indexed properties cant be assigned to